# Create a Vue Promise Function

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

Is it possible to create a Function for Javascript Promises in Vue JS.

I have multiple Axios calls to an API and I have two promises on each of them. Every Axios calls promise is the same. Is it possible to create a function that gets called after my axios call is completed.

```
axios.delete(url {data: item})
    .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
    })
    .then((data) => {
        axios.get(url)
        .then((response) => {
            this.name = response.data
    }).catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
       alert("There was an error, please try again.")
    });
})

 axios.post(url, JSON.stringify(item))
    .then((response) => {
         return response.data;
     })
     .then((data) => {
         axios.get(url)
         .then((response) => {
          this.test = response.data
   }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      alert("There was an error, please try again.")
   });
 })
```

Possibly something like this?

```
axios.post(url, JSON.stringify(item))
    .then(runThisFunction(response,data,error))
})

runThisFunction(response,data,error) {
   //Something like this but 
   .then((response) => {
         return response.data;
     })
     .then((data) => {
         axios.get(url)
         .then((response) => {
          this.test = response.data
   }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      alert("There was an error, please try again.")
   });
}
```

Comment: you are pretty close, simply use your function `runThisFunction` without passing arguments (ie not call it but let it be called from the promise `then` callback)

Comment: Alright I will try that, Thank you!